# workflow-4-node: assign value asynchronously and act on results

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, promise, workflow-4-node

I'm writing a workflow using [workflow-4-node](https://github.com/workflow-4-node/workflow-4-node/wiki/Basic-Concepts#1-workflows-and-activities). My workflow takes in a user input message. I'll extract a list of keywords from the message (asynchronously), and then trigger a serial of asynchronous actions base on the keywords.

For example, "I just had an apple, a can of beer, and a pancake". I'll pickup "apple", "beer" and "pancake", then add them into the user's consumption category: fruits, beverage and food, then base on the outcome of the categorization, further actions may be triggered. The chain may repeat part of itself and branch to different routes.

I started with a block workflow as below in my workflow.json

```
{
    @block:{
        msgin: 'I just had an apple, a can of beer, and a pancake',
        args:{
            '@func':{
                code:function() {
                    let msg = this.msgin;

                    return extractKW(msg); //Promise ['apple', 'beer', 'pancake']
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I know I can then code in main.js to loop through the result and trigger actions from there.

```
let engine = new ActivityExecutionEngine(wf);
engine.invoke().map(function (resolve) {
    categorize(resolve)...; 
});
```

However, this means the workflow logic is effectively moved into main.js. I'm trying to achieve this by defining the dependency and workflow logic inside workflow.json, so things I need to resolve:

1. Upon completion of `extractKW`, trigger the `categorize` function
2. Pass result from `extractKW` to `categorize` function and further result to subsequent functions.

Appreciate any advice.

Comment: I don't know workflow-4-node, but could you try to extend the @func code like this? `return extractKW(msg).then(function (arr) { return arr.map(categorize) });`. And if no other tasks should be performed, then in your JS code treat the returned promise as follows: `engine.invoke().then(function (arr) { .... });`.

Comment: @trincot, thanks for the comments. I hope I can resolve the inter-task dependency by configuration, instead of coding.

Comment: Wait, you have function literals and `@` signs in your JSON?

Comment: @Bergi It's workflow-4-node syntax